# odd behavior with dplyr summarise?

Tags: r, dplyr

I just started using dplyr and noticed some odd behavior, unless I'm not understanding the code correctly.

```
    library(dplyr)
library (plyr) #used elsewhere in the script to rename columns
    t <- mtcars
    by_cyl <- group_by(mtcars, cyl)
    summarise(by_cyl, sum(disp), mean(hp))
      sum(disp) mean(hp)
    1    7383.1 146.6875
```

Shouldn't this give the mean and sum 'disp' by cylinder type?

Thank you
-al

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %.%
 group_by(cyl) %.%
 summarise(sum(disp), mean(hp))
```

By chaining together the commands with `%.%` you dont need to reference the data.frame every time

And you can write it in a single line if you like:

```
mtcars %.% group_by(cyl) %.% summarise(sum(disp), mean(hp))
```

Have a look at the [Introduction to dplyr](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html).

Comment: This is functionally equivalent to the OP's question.  Indeed, dropping the `disp=` and `hp=` argument names returns the desired output.

Comment: @AriB.Friedman correct, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestion, however, I found the problem. The problem I was encountering was because I was loading the plyr library after I had loaded the dplyr library.

Comment: "Thank you" was not the answer, if you keep reading you would see that the answer was to load the libraries in a different order. My original code worked just fine if dplyr was loaded after plyr.